# ansible string.split() with multiple delimiters

Tags: split, ansible

I'm having a hard time trying to split the string into list using multiple delimiters. I could just split it twice like follows:

```
myString.split(':')[1].split('.')
```

However this would look so unelegant.
In my head, I'd like to do something like:

```
myString.split(': | .')
```

Is that even a thing?

Comment: can you give any feedback on the answer? Or accept the answer if it works?

Answer (score 6):

I can think of two ways to do it.

**Replace all delimeters with a single delimeter and then split:**

```
- set_fact: my_list="{{ (myString | regex_replace(':|.', ':')).split(':') }}"
```

**Split using regular expression:**

```
- set_fact: mystr="{{ myString | regex_findall('([^:.]+)') }} "
```

Comment: Yes, as I said, I know I can do it other way. My point is, can the split() be used in ansible to split using multiple delimiters? This answer does not answer my question.

Comment: Answer to your question is No. You cant do it with only split() function. You have to ask this as a feature request from ansible.